# OLE Error in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ole

I have Windows Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition SP2 with

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (X64)   Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

I downloaded CAPICOM Platform SDK Redistributable: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=860EE43A-A843-462F-ABB5-FF88EA5896F6&displaylang=en

and installed it from 
c:\Windows\syswow64 with c:\Windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe capicom.dll and it got registered succesfully.

When I tried to run

```
DECLARE @S varchar(255) 
DECLARE @D varchar(255)
DECLARE @O int

EXEC @C = sp_OACreate 'CAPICOM.EncryptedData', @O OUT
IF @C <> 0
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_oageterrorinfo @O, @S out, @D out 
  SELECT err=CONVERT(VARBINARY(4),@C), source=@S, description=@D
  RETURN
END
```

and I got error message.

```
0x80040154  ODSOLE Extended Procedure    Class not registered
```

What should I do? How should I check if CAPICOM.DLL is correctly registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has a walkthrough of how to register a surrogate for CAPICOM so it can be used from 64-bit processes.

- [64 bit C# with a 32 bit VB6 COM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611651/64-bit-c-sharp-with-a-32-bit-vb6-com-object/8908105#8908105)

I have actually done this to use CAPICOM from 64-bit SQL Server and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [reason](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932872).
Is there a 64 bit version of this component?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am afraid there is no 64bit version of this component.

Answer (score 1):

CAPICOM will not ship 64 bit afaik, is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375732(VS.85).aspx):

> CAPICOM is a 32-bit only component
>   that is available for use in the
>   following operating systems: Windows
>   Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows
>   XP, and Windows 2000. Instead, use the
>   .NET Framework to implement security
>   features. For more information, see
>   [Alternatives to Using CAPICOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778518(VS.85).aspx)

Between the crypto functions in SQL 2005 itslef and the CRL procedures access to .Net crypto, frankly I don't see any reason to stick with the COM crypto API. Certainly, I understand that you can have legacy code and need to support it, bur for new development definetly a big no no.

Comment: It is about third party application that I support. Is there any way in 64bit SQL server to decrypt the data that was encrypted with CAPICOM?

Comment: SQL Server own function won't decrypt CAPICOM encrypted data because they use their own format (they append the initialization vector for instance). But a CLR function or procedure is perfectly capable of decrypting CAPICOM data using the System.Cryptography components.