# Why unable to call third party dll when it run in 64 bit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I develop program in c# and my machine is 64 bit OS. The problem is when i run my application in 32 bit OS some dll cannot be called in the application Like Microsoft report viewer and Microsoft Interop. But other dll's are good and running. I have this problem for days and no clue what get it wrong. This is the error when the program use the Report.Viewer.

```
 System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.Reset()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer..ctor()
```

Comment: You need to change your application to 32 bit to use 32 bit external libraries. This question is duplicate for sure, but I'm too lazy to search the duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037672/2826535 and many, many others: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=32+bit+dll+in+c%23&t=ffnt&ia=qa