# Can an x64 program access an x86 COM object on Windows x64?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access x86 COM from x64 .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359331/access-x86-com-from-x64-net)

I have a COM object which is only x86.

My program runs native x64 (not through WOW64 emulation).
Is it possible that my program can access the x86 COM object?
Or do I need to port the x86 COM object to x64?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359331/access-x86-com-from-x64-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but only in out-of-proc mode.

Comment: And how do you do that if you have no control over the dll, it's installed as part of another app.

Comment: You need no control over thr DLL if it's properly registred as a COM object. COM runtime makes all the work.