# "interops made for a different target platorm." and "ActiveX not properly registered"

Tags: dll, 64-bit, target, platform

Thank you for any and all help... I've never seen this bug before... I have several vendor supplied DLLs for talking to a Signature Capture Device. We build our C# windows app platform target set to "any cpu" on an XP x86 machine. When the application is run on Win7 32-bit computer it works fine. When it is run on Win7 64bit computer it fails.

Running the Visual Studio 2010 debugger on Win 7 x64 in "Debug mode" works fine. Running in Release mode on Win7 x64 fails.

I can change the platform to target x64 then Release mode gives "interops made for a different target platorm." When I delete and recreate the interops for 64 bit target I get "ActiveX not properly registered".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you module not depends of 32 bits libs.
Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) or [Fuslogvw.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2006/07/12/663834.aspx) to diagnose module load fail.

To interop 32/64 bits COM see [Access x86 COM from x64 .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448039/47733)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change the Project->Properties->Build->Platform Target from "any cpu" to "x86". The application now runs on win7 64 bit and 32 bit and XP x86.