# Can MATLAB for 64 bit use pre-compiled 32 bit mex files?

Tags: matlab

I have access to a library with pre-compiled 32 bit mex files (Windows: `.mexw32`, Linux: `.mexa32`). I am having a hard time compiling the library myself for a 64 bit machine, so I was wondering if there is a way to make MATLAB 64 bit work with 32 bit mex files.

Comment: As far as I know you're out of luck. Take your compilation troubles as a demonstration why interpreted languages like Matlab are so awesome.

Comment: @AmV: perhaps this would help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bsflnue-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general [accessing 32bit code from a 64bit executable is nontrivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128445/calling-32bit-code-from-64bit-process). Therefore I doubt they have implemented this in MATLAB natively...

Answer (score 1):

No a 64-bit program cannot use 32-bit shared libraries.  One option is to install the 32-bit version of MATLAB on your machine as well.