# How to call 32bit only 3rd party managed code from 64bit application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, migration, 64-bit

We're migrating a legacy system that runs under Citrix from .NET2/32 to .NET4/64. Part of the existing system uses a product called BarTender from Seagull Scientific that is used to print out barcodes.

Due to various constraints we must use BarTender from the application but from a technical perspective, we can't directly call the BarTender 32bit (only) managed code that the bartender controls consist of from our 64bit application. I know that we'll have to go across a process boundary by some method as the two halves will have to run in separate spaces.

Following various suggestions on Stack and the web in general, I've gone down the route of trying to create intermediate COM objects (i.e., create a project in .NET and register for COM interop) in 64bit and 32bit guises to see if I can call those to provide this "step down" from 64 to 32 bit but I either end up going round in circles using tlbimp.exe to create a 64 big runtime callable wrapper or to use regasm.exe to go the other way around.

I'm sure that this has all been done before but I've not found a complete guide that describes the correct steps and appropriate tools to use.

*Create your 64bit application like this.
*Do these steps or create these intermediates by the following process
*Create your 32bit application like this.
*Set it up like this so that it can be called.

We MUST run in 64bit on Citrix, so forcing the application to run in 32bit isn't an option.

I've already looked at this article

http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/
and the suggestions in this post

[Calling 32bit Code from 64bit Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128445/calling-32bit-code-from-64bit-process)

But I can't quite get things to marry up.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your requirements are completely contradictory.  If *you* must run in 64-bit code then surely *any* app must run in 64-bit mode.  Including that barcode scanner software.  The only way ahead then is to ask the vendor to provide you with a 64-bit version of their code.

Comment: If only it were that simple. The vendor doesn't currently provide a 64 bit non-specific version of their components. It's 32bit or nothing. The 64bit aspect is to do with the main application. The bartender side is for printing our barcode labels. So they can be two separate things running as two separate processes.
But you are right, it is pretty contradictory !

Comment: Both of those articles are correct in that this is the best way to do what you are asking for.  Unfortunately, they are theoretical and do not help you actually do it.  But, according to this article, there is another way: [Run 32 DLL from 64 OS](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/267554/Using-32-bit-COM-Object-from-64-bit-Application). But, I am skeptical. Let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Our final solution has been to create a 32bit proxy that is a singleton and maintains the link to our 32bit application via the vendors .NET API. We make calls to it by Diagnostics.Process.Start to shell out to it passing the data we need to give it as command line parameters. I suspect this would be rubbish if we were sending large amounts of data in quick succession - we'd probably go a TCP/IP/UDP/WCF route for that, but this does the job nicely. The main thing from our perspective is the singleton pattern and it being 32bit to match the vendors API.