# Citrix API in 64-bit WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, 64-bit, citrix

How can I use the 32-bit only Citrix libraries in my 64-bit only WPF application?

(Edit: or is there another way I can integrate Citrix into my WPF application?)

We're developing a load testing utility for evaluating our company's desktop product in various deployment scenarios and workflows. The basic idea is that the tool, which is a WPF application, opens several Remote Desktop windows and starts the product application, runs a given workflow, exits, and logs off.

We would like to be able to support Citrix connections natively within the tool, with a similar UX to RD. However, the libraries appear to be 32-bit only. Now, normally this wouldn't be a problem except that we have to build the application as 64-bit since connecting to say, 50 or 100 RD sessions requires 64-bit memory access (it was initially x86, but we ran into memory issues when initially connecting to certain terminal servers with just a few users). Changing the build to x64 resolved this and allowed us to fire up as many as 100 RD sessions.

We can still fire up Citrix sessions with ICA files using `Process.Start()` - which works - but it's not ideal as each process is detached from the primary process and I can't control any other parameters within the session such as container size, scaling, etc. without modifying the ICA file first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling 32bit Code from 64bit Process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128445/calling-32bit-code-from-64bit-process)