# FFI with 64bit Ruby and a 32bit dll

Tags: ruby, dll

I am hoping to gather some clarification and a better understanding of an issue I'm currently dealing with.

I wrote some simple test code which pulled in a 32bit dll file using FFI. My simple tests worked fine. Now, I started this project on a 32bit computer. When I went to continue the project, I was using a 64bit computer with 64bit Ruby installed.

I've tested this both on the 64bit production server and my 64bit laptop.  I've done some research and I think I've gathered the issue, but I need a better understanding and verification.

So, for clarification, the dll file I need to utilize is 32bit. I've gotten a simple application functioning on a 32bit computer, but I am unable to get it running on the either of two 64bit computers.

In order to tie in with a 32bit dll, do I have to be running 32bit ruby?  Will FFI only tie in with a dll of equal (32/64) architecture?

Also, best I can find, there is no 64bit version of the dll file as it's essentially legacy support. And, most production environments are 64bit (windows).

Comment: Could you show error message and explain when it occurs in your mixed-architecture solution? Also, if any of your research gives a partial answer to your question, worth linking to relevant articles etc to avoid duplicated effort.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128445/calling-32bit-code-from-64bit-process