# Load DLL directly from go-bindata byte-slice

Tags: windows, go, dll, linker, bindata

I'm building a windows application that uses a third-party DLL. In order to bundle everything into one executable, I have embedded said DLL as a `go-bindata` asset into my binary.

Currently I drop the embedded DLL to the local file system when the application runs for the first time and then load it with `syscall.NewLazyDLL()`. That works fine so far!

I was wondering, though, if anyone knows a solution that would allow me to load the DLL directly from the in-memory byte-slice that the `go-bindata` asset provides, without first dropping the DLL as a file to the local filesystem.

I am currently looking at Go's `runtime.syscall_loadlibrary()` method in `syscall_windows.go` that `syscall.NewLazyDLL` calls at some point but don't really have an idea where to go from here...

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372751/c-sharp-loading-native-dll-from-byte) and this [github repository](https://github.com/dretax/DynamicDllLoader) that seem to deal with a similar issue, but all related to C/C++/C#.

Thoughts?